# How to refresh view without refreshing page in an angularjs app

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

I have a simple app that lists contact reports,
in it i made a list view that fetches data from Mongolab.

On that i also made an input form that makes a new contact report in the list when submitted

the function i use in the controller is modelled from angular's example on their site :

```
app.factory('Contact',function($mongolabResource){
    return $mongolabResource('contacts');
});

function ContactCreateCtrl($scope,$location,Contact) {
Contact.save(contact,function(){
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
```

the $location.path() is the callback that reloads the page.

how do i rewrite this so that when the data has been submitted ( .save() is successful ) the view reloads without the page reloading?

i tried deleting and then redefining the array but doesnt seem to work :

```
Contact.save(contact,function(){
        delete $scope.contacts;
        $scope.contacts = Contact.query();
    });
```

i would like to implement this on the delete function as well. Can somebody point me to where i can learn this?

Much thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you need to reload the view?

Comment: so my list shows the newly added item, right now it achieves it by executing the $location.path(); if i remove that the list doesnt update, but when i manually reload the browser, it shows the new item

Comment: im just after a smoother app experience without page reloads

Comment: A view reload shouldn't be necessary as bindings ensure the update occurs. Can you add a simple example on Plunker or jsFiddle?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller thats what i thought, i wish i knew how paste the whole app and include include my partial/template htmls in jsFiddle... to be quick, its quite similar to : http://angularjs.org/#project-html in the 'wiring up a backend' section. Can you look at that for now? will try to make an example on jsFiddle in the meantime

Comment: When you insert the new item, there are two ways to refresh the list: manually fetch a new one, or insert the item returned from a save into your scope variable. Which are you trying? Also, you can use partials in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NEuJ6/

Comment: Jush figured out the fiddle, thanks for the insight, its at jsfiddle.net/Y223F. 
i just figured out i can use .push into the array, but is that best practice? i mean its pushing into scope, but its not quite pulling from the database, although its the same data. im thinking can it cause discrepancies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I updated your fiddle to fetch the value from the database: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/Y223F/2/.

```js
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope,Contact ) {
  $scope.updateContacts = function () {
    Contact.query( function( data ) {
      $scope.contacts = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.save = function( newContact ) {
    Contact.save( newContact, function() {
      $scope.updateContacts();
    });
  };

  // The initial data load
  $scope.updateContacts();  
});
```

Two things to note:

(1) I moved your Mongo query into a function so that it can be called again when the new record is created;

(2) the $mongolabResource expects a callback to be executed on success; your app flickered because you didn't provide one. In other words, from the time you called the query to the time fetch was complete, your list was empty. Instead, we want it to change *only* when we get the new data. I changed that too.

In terms of adding the item manually or fetching from the database, best practice is based on the use case and there are trade-offs. But for small data such as this, just fetch from the DB.

Comment: ah i see, didnt cross my mind to make it a function. thx Josh

Comment: @MarkRajcok I know it works; but as I said, it causes flickering. Here's the same fiddle with the callback removed and the value directly assigned: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/Y223F/3/. Direct assignment may be a useful trick for initial retrieval, but beyond that it degrades UX.

Comment: Sorry @Josh, I didn't read your answer carefully enough.  I deleted my comment (before you replied).  What you have is definitely better (+1).

Comment: @MarkRajcok I was too quick! No worries... (and SO should notify me of changes wherever I am in the page, instead of just the top, so I could have seen it before I posted a reply)

Comment: Also, if you are into MongoLab and AngularJS you might want to check a feature-complete $http, resource-like adapter for MongoLab: https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab-promise. Demo here: http://embed.plnkr.co/Y8sg4V/preview

Comment: Very small trick is to add contact into collection on client side, then make request to server and update contacts on success. This will make ui more responsive - we pretend that contact was added before actual adding.

Comment: alwasy use ng-init="init()" next to ng-controller in your html and then call $scope.updateContacts();  from init. Angularjs calls this method at the correct time after loading some prerequisites.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch You'll have to be more specific about to what "prerequisites" you're referring the dependency injection isn't handling.

Answer (score 0):

got this to work, but still not sure about pushing into the array at the scope, would be better if we could fetch from database

```
function ContactCreateCtrl($scope,$location,Contact) {
    Contact.save(contact,function(){
    $scope.contacts.push(contact);
});
```

also i would need the _id object thats automatically generated by the db, for linking purposes. this method doesnt give me the _id, any insights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my answer for how I cleared data in the view after sign out from firebase using the firebase auth service. The data was still persisting after calling `$scope.currentUser = null;` on the signout method. Had to reload to see the data change. Not best UX.

```
$scope.getCurrentUser = function() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                $scope.currentUser = user;
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                $scope.currentUser = null;
                console.log('user not signed in.');
            }
        });
    }

$scope.getCurrentUser();


$scope.signout = function() {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
          // Sign-out successful.
          console.log('signed out success');
          $scope.getCurrentUser();
        }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
          console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

so calling the getUserData method and making the currentUser = null there updated the view without a reload. this is an example using firebase but with a few adjustments it might apply to your needs for clearing data from view without a full page reload. Firebase does the heavy lifting here of clearing out the user object but my view doesn't care until I check again in my getCurrentUser method to see if there is still a user and if not then clear it from the $scope without reloading the view.